# dispatch_group EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-instruction

I'm getting a weird `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` crash when I'm using `dispatch_group_t`. I'm using `MagicalRecord` and my success block gets triggered after a `MagicalRecord` save. My `dispatch_group_leave(group)` line crashes if there are no changes to save - otherwise it works fine. I have several of these similar calls that are a part of the group, and I'm experiencing the same issue with all of them. I'm totally lost...any ideas?

Below is my code:

```
// Create a group that will wait until all the profile elements have been update before hiding the activity indicator
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self.user readProfileWithContext:self.backgroundMOC
                          success:^{
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                  [self.view setPreferencesForUser:self.user];
                              });
                              // I get the crash on this line when Magical Record doesn't have any changes
                              dispatch_group_leave(group);
                          } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                              dispatch_group_leave(group);
                          }];
```

**Edit**
I don't get any output in the console, but I do get this as the issue in the backtrace (not sure if this is helpful):
[image]

Comment: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION probably means an assertion is failing inside libdispatch itself. What is the complete backtrace of the crash? Do you get any output in the system console?

Comment: @GregParker Hmmm...I'm not sure how to fix that issue. I added a screenshot of the backtrace

Comment: That's not a backtrace, that's just the assembly display of one frame in the backtrace.

Comment: Looks like the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/24337791/900873, something is probably being deallocated early.