# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on dispatch_semaphore_dispose

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, grand-central-dispatch

I am getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on dispatch_semaphore_dispose but don't really know how to track down the root cause of this.  My code makes use of dispatch_async, dispatch_group_enter and so on.

UPDATE:
The cause of the crash is due to the fact that the webserviceCall (see code below) never calls onCompletion and when the code is run again, I got the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.  I verified this is indeed the case, but not sure why or how to prevent this.

[image]

Code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

     for (...) {
        if (...) {
            dispatch_group_enter(group);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

               [self webserviceCall:url onCompletion:^{
                     dispatch_group_leave(group);
               }];
            });
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        // call completion handler passed in by caller
    });
});
```

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I looked at that, it didn't help me.  Notice mine is EXC_I386_INVOP as well.

Comment: This is likely an ARC problem. Post anything you are doing with dispatch groups, semaphores, or dispatch_sync. ARC may be attempting to dispose of a semaphore that something already set to NULL.

Comment: For sake use weakSelf inside the block.

Comment: FYI 1. If you create you reach to a `fatalError`/`assertionFailure` written by **yourself**, you'll get an error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. Hence you should see why you've reached your own assertion ie look into its message. That being said, this error is generated by the **compiler**. 2. My point is that the compilers also use `fatalError` and many of the errors we see are because of that

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From your stack trace, `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` occurred because **`dispatch_group_t` was released while it was still locking (waiting for `dispatch_group_leave`)**.

According to what you found, this was what happened :

- `dispatch_group_t group` was created. *`group`'s retain count = 1.*
- `-[self webservice:onCompletion:]` captured the `group`. *`group`'s retain count = 2.*
- `dispatch_async(...., ^{ dispatch_group_wait(group, ...) ... });` captured the `group` again. *`group`'s retain count = 3.*
- Exit the current scope. `group` was released. *`group`'s retain count = 2.*
- `dispatch_group_leave` was never called.
- `dispatch_group_wait` was timeout. The `dispatch_async` block was completed. `group` was released. *`group`'s retain count = 1.*
- You called this method again. When `-[self webservice:onCompletion:]` was called again, the old `onCompletion` block was replaced with the new one. So, the old `group` was released. *`group`'s retain count = 0.* `group` was deallocated. That resulted to `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

**To fix this, I suggest you should find out why `-[self webservice:onCompletion:]` didn't call `onCompletion` block, and fix it. Then make sure the next call to the method will happen after the previous call did finish.**

---

In case you allow the method to be called many times whether the previous calls did finish or not, you might find someone to hold `group` for you :

- You can change the timeout from 2 seconds to `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` or a reasonable amount of time that all `-[self webservice:onCompletion]` should call their `onCompletion` blocks by the time. So that the block in `dispatch_async(...)` will hold it for you.
  OR
- You can add `group` into a collection, such as `NSMutableArray`.

---

I think it is **the best approach to create a dedicate class for this action**. When you want to make calls to *webservice*, you then create an object of the class, call the method on it with the completion block passing to it that will release the object. In the class, there is an ivar of `dispatch_group_t` or `dispatch_semaphore_t`.

Comment: Wow, amazing analysis.  If I add group into a collection, it will never be deallocated though, right? I may not be able to fix the non-returning webservice because this is a framework, and I can't prevent others from creating webservice call that doesn't return (erroneously), I want to make sure my framework doesn't crash in those circumstances.

Comment: Yes, so you must remove it from the collection when you finish using it.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Many thanks! In my case, I only called dispatch_group_leave in onCompletion, but forgot to call it in onCancellation. Calling dispatch_group_leave in any condition fixed my problem.

Comment: Helped me a lot , I announced a ivar dispatch group, but didn't enter or leave in compare.

Comment: For me it was very weird, I had 2 parameters having the same name by mistake and I was getting this error on runtime.

Answer (score 10):

I had a different issue that brought me to this question, which will probably be more common than the overrelease issue in the accepted answer.

Root cause was our completion block being called *twice* due to bad if/else fallthrough in the network handler, leading to two calls of `dispatch_group_leave` for every one call to `dispatch_group_enter`.

#### Completion block called multiple times:

```
dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self badMethodThatCallsMULTIPLECompletions:^(NSString *completion) {

    // this block is called multiple times
    // one `enter` but multiple `leave`

    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];
```

#### Debug via the dispatch_group's `count`

Upon the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`, you should still have access to your dispatch_group in the debugger. [DispatchGroup: check how many "entered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610271/dispatchgroup-check-how-many-entered)

Print out the dispatch_group and you'll see:

`<OS_dispatch_group: group[0x60800008bf40] = { xrefcnt = 0x2, refcnt = 0x1, port = 0x0, count = -1, waiters = 0 }>`

When you see `count = -1` it indicates that you've over-left the dispatch_group. Be sure to `dispatch_enter` and `dispatch_leave` the group in matched pairs.

Comment: The tip about `count = -1` was very helpful - thanks!

Comment: I had a similar situation - although using a group=DispatchGroup() with group.enter() and the corresponding group.leave() in a completion block (that was being called multiple times).  In the debugger, the count for the group was 1073741823 -- which as a signed 32-bit int is also -1

Answer (score 8):

My problem was took `IBOutlet` but didn't connect with interface builder and using in swift file.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can we find out from the error message as to which IBOutlet could be unlinked?

Comment: If you have only one 1 InterfaceBuilder for that Class then you can check every `IBOutlet` connected or disconnected symbol in your .swift or .m / .h file.

Comment: Had the same issue, was referencing a action from a button without adding the button itself as a IBOutlet.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes all it takes to get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` is a missing `return` statement.

It certainly was my case.

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I was creating objects that I wanted to be stored in a NSMutableDictionary but I never initialized the dictionary.  Therefore the objects were getting deleted by garbage collection and breaking later.  Check that you have at least one strong reference to the objects youre interacting with.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
requestOptions.synchronous            = NO;
```

Was trying to do this with dispatch_group

Answer (score 1):

I landed here because of an XCTestCase, in which I'd disabled most of the tests by prefixing them with 'no_' as in no_testBackgroundAdding. Once I noticed that most of the answers had something to do with locks and threading, I realized the test contained a few instances of XCTestExpectation with corresponding waitForExpectations. They were all in the disabled tests, but apparently Xcode was still evaluating them at some level.

In the end I found an XCTestExpectation that was defined as @property but lacked the @synthesize. Once I added the synthesize directive, the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that it was in my init().
Probably the "weak self" killed him while the init wasn't finished.
I moved it from the init and it solved my issue.