# dispatch_group_leave crash in swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, healthkit

This happens very rarely. Here is the last line of the stack trace:

```
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000197a85a9c dispatch_group_leave + 48
```

dispatch_group_leave is called in a complete closure which is invoked like this:

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                { () -> Void in
                    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
                        quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                        options: statisticOptions,
                        anchorDate: anchorDate,
                        intervalComponents: interval)
                    query.initialResultsHandler = {

                        complete()
```

So we dispatch to a background thread, run a HKStatisticsCollectionQuery, and then call a function parameter closure called complete. Inside complete is where the dispatch_group_leave is called and the crash happens.

Any ideas are most appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43548031/1265393

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If `dispatch_group_leave` call isn't balanced with `dispatch_group_enter` then crash may happen.

Comment: Interesting. I have an enter before the first closure is called. hmmm.

Comment: I think this was it. Certain leaves were getting called too fast. Moved all the enters and the notify to before the leaves can be called. Thanks!

Comment: @mustafa is there a way to prevent the case of calling dispatch_group_leave more than it should? i.e., for cases that I can't tell for sure that completion block - of which in it the dispatch_group_leave is called - will not be called more than once?

Comment: @ofer2980 did you find a way?

Comment: We can add a little bit sleep thread call after dispatch_group_leave. It will help dispatch_group to apply concurrency rules. It saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

In the worst case, you can check the discount group's `count` via its `debugDescription` String:

```
let count = self.groupExecuting.debugDescription.components(separatedBy: ",").filter({$0.contains("count")}).first!.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).filter({Int($0) != nil})
assert(count.first != "0")
```

This strategy is further explored in this question: [DispatchGroup: check how many "entered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610271/dispatchgroup-check-how-many-entered)

Comment: What in tarnation

Comment: @PranoyC This should obviously not be used in the production code, but was really helpful for debugging.