# DispatchGroup: check how many "entered"

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using Swift 3 `DispatchGroup` to wait until multiple async operations are finished (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35906703/27404) which works perfect and as expected.

Is there a way to check how many operations are entered already, like `dispatchGroup.count` or something like that?

Answer (score 17):

You can see counts of enters to the group in debug description:

> OS_dispatch_group: group[0x60000221d950] = { xref = 3, ref = 3,
>   **count = 2**, gen = 0, waiters = 0, notifs = 1 }

and extract int value out of it:

```
let count = dispatchGroup.debugDescription.components(separatedBy: ",").filter({$0.contains("count")}).first?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).compactMap{Int($0)}.first
```

Comment: That's hardcore, but thumbs up for the attempt. :)

Comment: Will this code work in "Release build configuration" since debugDescription of dispatchGroup is used ??.

Comment: Can I get the "leave" count?

Comment: Wow, it works like a charms ^^.

Answer (score 6):

NO, nothing. You need to balance your `enter()` and `leave()` by yourself without counting.

[DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

Comment: Is there any analog with the counter?