# Why am I getting "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: xcode, swift

I am getting

> "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

in this code

```
else {
    let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue
    let longitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lon"]!).doubleValue
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
    self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate

    annotation.title = places[activePlace]["name"]
    self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

on

```
 let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue
```

here is my active place variable witch is in a previous table view

var activePlace = -1]

still in the tableview I have this

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        activePlace = indexPath.row

        return indexPath

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "newPlace" {

            activePlace = -1


        }
```

in the second view controller ( where I have the problem )
I have this in the view did load

```
manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.delegate = self
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

if activePlace == -1 {

    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()


} else {



    let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue

    let longitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lon"]!).doubleValue

    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)

    self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate


    annotation.title = places[activePlace]["name"]

    self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

This code was already there and worked perfect until I added the following code

```
@IBAction func addCurentLoc(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        var newCoordinate2 = self.Map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

        var location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate2.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate2.longitude)

        title = "new address"


        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation();
        annotation.title = title;
        annotation.coordinate = self.Map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            var title = ""

            if (error == nil) {

                if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                    var subThouroughfare:String = ""
                    var thouroughfare:String = ""

                    if p.subThoroughfare != nil {

                        subThouroughfare = p.subThoroughfare!

                    }

                    if p.thoroughfare != nil {

                        thouroughfare = p.thoroughfare!

                    }

                    title = "\(subThouroughfare) \(thouroughfare)"


                }

            }

            if title == "" {

                title = "Added \(NSDate())"

            }

            places.append(["name":title,"lat":"\(newCoordinate2.latitude)","lon":"\(newCoordinate2.longitude)"])

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate2

            annotation.title = title

            self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }

        self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation);



        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
            viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!{
                if(annotation is MKUserLocation){
                    return nil;
                }

                let pinView: Void = mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
                let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,reuseIdentifier:"MyIdentifier");
                return pinAnnotationView;

                       }



    }
```

I have been looking for an a solution for a while and can't find out, note that I have checked this answer

[EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) on dispatch_semaphore_dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337791/exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0-on-dispatch-semaphore-dis)

as well as this one

[what does Error "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804654/what-does-error-thread-1exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0)

but haven't found the solution, thanks for the help

EDIT: Please note that this question has been modified to be a bit clearer, please ask if you need more info.

Comment: Put a breakpoints and you can find at which line you are getting this error.

Comment: put the expression print(places[activePlace]["lat"]) before your first assignment (as first statement after else { ) and show us the result

Comment: @user3441734 the result is exactly the same except the error message is on the  print(places[activePlace]["lat"]) line

Comment: it seem that your array places is declared as implicitly unwrap optional and is still nil while you try to access it. from the code you provide in your question, we can not see, what exactly you did.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the first line of your else then type in lldb:

`po places[activePlace]` - does it return value or nil?

if returns value type `places[activePlace]["lat"]!`

One of them will probably return nil, the error you're getting means you're implicitly unwrapping a nil.

Comment: How do you type something in the LLDB ?

Comment: 1) Run the app
2) Open bottom pane if not already open
3) on the left side you have all the variables in current scope, on the right there are your log messages and that's where you type your commands once you hit a breakpoint

Comment: this is the message I get po places[activePlace]
fatal error: Array index out of range
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb)

Comment: well the compiler message is quite clear here. You want to access an element that doesn't exist in an array. Can not help you any more with the code you posted. Read your code again, check where you set activePlace variable and work from there

Comment: thanks for answering @66o I have been looking through the code but haven't figured it out , however I have added code in the question with should help